# Envoyer deployment hooks - command not found

Tags: laravel, envoyer.io

I use envoyer.io for deploying my apps.

Recently I removed compiled css/js files from my git repo. Instead I want to compile them on production server. I tired to add a couple of deployment hooks after composer install. But without any success, each my try failed with "command not found"

For example, one of the hooks look like:

```
cd {{release}}

npm install
```

I tried both {{release}} and full path and I always got

```
"bash: line 2: gulp: command not found"
```

Though when I did this from console it worked.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `npm install` does not install gulp itself, but rather elixir and all of the pieces it uses to use gulp.

When you install gulp, you should install it globally: `npm install --global gulp`